# Get colour of rectangle at specific x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors, pixel

I want to be able to get the color of a pixel at specific x,y
 co-ordinates on a canvas (A rectangles color, but the pixel will
 sufice).

Is there anyway of doing this with normal javascript without adding any additional libraries?

I'm developing it with the idea of mobile platforms and would prefer not to use external libraries. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the answer let's go straight to the [source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#pixel-manipulation).

You want `context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);`

This grabs a rectangle out of the canvas and returns all the pixels there in the form of an "[ImageData](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#imagedata)" object. This object in turn has a "data" attribute which is, for all intents and purposes, just a normal Array (it's not, but you can pretend it is if you just want to read from it).

The data array looks like

`[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,...]` where r,g,b, and a are the red, green, blue, and alpha channels of the colour of one pixel. The pixels are ordered as if they were being read in an english book (left to right, then top to bottom).

For you purposes, you can just do `var pixel = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data`. Then if you want to know the red part, do `pixel[0]`, green? `pixel[1]`... and so on.

However remark that in my emprical tests, getImageData is an *incredibly* expensive operation (especially in Firefox; Chrome handles it faster, but with less bounds-checking). If you expect to do this query many times per-second, it may be worth getting a larger rectangle to cache some results. Of course this won't work if the pixel data is rapidly changing.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas' getImageData()  returns an ImageData object that copies the pixel data for the specified rectangle on a canvas.

```
var color = canvas2d_context.getImageData(pixel_coord_x, pixel_coord_y, 1, 1);

console.log('pixel red value:   ' + color.data[0]);
console.log('pixel green value: ' + color.data[1]);
console.log('pixel blue value:  ' + color.data[1]);
console.log('pixel alpha value: ' + color.data[1]);
```

...mostly from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp